# How to exclude a specific number from random method while filling array

Tags: java, arrays, random, while-loop

I'm looking for a solution for exclude one number from Random method filling an array. I wrote a following code but instead of using "i--" I would like to use while statement. Does anyone have an idea how to handle it?

```
Random random = new Random();
int[] tab = new int[10];
    for(int i=0 ; i<10 ; i++) {
    int randomNumber = random.nextInt(11);
        if(randomNumber == 5) {
            i--;
            continue;
        }
        tab[i] = randomNumber;
}
```

Comment: So your actual question is just how to convert your for loop into a while loop? Because you already did that whole number excluding thing in the code above.

Answer (score 0):

You could generate a random integer between 0 (inclusive) to 10 (exclusive) and then "shift" the values to omit 5.

```
Random random = new Random();
for (int i=0 ; i<10 ; i++) {
    int randomNumber = random.nextInt(10);
    if (randomNumber < 5) {
        tab[i] = randomNumber;
    }
    else {
        tab[i] = randomNumber + 1;
    }
}
```

(**EDIT**: Show full code including the loop.)

**EDIT 2**: OP wants a solution that regenerates `randomNumber` until it is not 5:

```
Random random = new Random();
for (int i=0 ; i<10 ; i++) {
    int randomNumber;
    while ((randomNumber.nextInt(11)) != 5) {
        tab[i] = randomNumber;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well I would rather use while loop but your solution solves a problem either. Thanks for comment.

Comment: This is the body to the loop! I'll edit it to show the full code.

Comment: Yes i got it, but I'm curious if is it possible to obtain the same effect using while loop? I tried to find out a solution using while loop and I still have no idea how to do this.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how a `while` loop would come into play here? Do you mean something like regenerating `randomNumber` until it is not 5?

Comment: Regenerate randomNumber if the randomNumber is 5, and regenerate it till randomNumber != 5, then put it into tab[i].

Comment: I've updated my answer to include this solution. I personally don't recommend it. In theory, there's nothing to stop the RNG generating from a trillion 5's in a row at some point! (See the [infinite monkey theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_monkey_theorem)).

Comment: Yes I see that the loop could never end. But I'm thinking about using a counter or smth like this.